# Is it possible to reverse a hashed password?

Tags: passwords, hash, password-cracking, bcrypt

Is it possible to reverse a password hashed with bcrypt?

Comment: In general, no (due to the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)).

Comment: How is it possible for companies to leak passwords? Isn't hashing passwords an industry standard? @user

Comment: I have removed the question about recommendations because that's a completely different question, you have not stated your requirements and constraints, and there are standard libraries to use: https://www.google.com/search?q=standard+password+hashing+function

Answer (score 3):

No. Hashing is not reversible.

What is usually referred to as "cracking a hash" is to throw lots and lots of strings on the hash function and comparing the output with the list of hashes (a.k.a. "brute force").

Answer (score 2):

If the password is in a dictionary (such as [rockyou.txt](https://www.kaggle.com/wjburns/common-password-list-rockyoutxt)) or is easily guessable, then tools like [hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/) or [john the ripper](https://www.openwall.com/john/) may be able to crack the hashed password using brute force.

Comment: While the steps are accurate, password crackers and cryptographers try to avoid the word 'reverse' in this context, because it can confuse people into thinking that the process can actually be reversed. 'Cracking' is the more acceptable term.

Comment: @RoyceWilliams,  Thanks for the suggestion.  I agree, 'cracking' is a better word to use.  I've edited my answer.